# errorprovider or message box?

Tags: c#, winforms, errorprovider

I have a simplr windows form input(student name,studentid) to display to a listbox.

I need to check for duplicate student id in listbox before i add a value.
Can I use error provider on student id text box to do this?
any help much appreciated

please check last bit of my code below -is for/foreach loop required?
Thanks

```
private void txtSid_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        bool can = false;
        int sid = 0;


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSid.Text))
        {

            ep1.SetError(txtSid, "Please Enter Student ID");
            can = true;
        }
        else if (!int.TryParse(txtSid.Text, out sid))
        {
            ep1.SetError(txtSid, "Student ID must be a number");
            can = true;
        }
        else
         for (int i = 0; i < lstDisplay.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            if (lstDisplay.Items[i].ToString().Contains(txtSid.Text))
            {
             ep1.SetError(txtSid, "Student ID already added");
            can = true;
            }
        {
                        }

        e.Cancel = can;
    }
```

Comment: For my personal taste users hate messege boxes and never read them, i also dont like the error provider, i would use a label with red fore color to prompt errors to the users (my personal point of view)

Comment: @jonathana In theory, I agree.  Works great for websites.  But in WinForms, that can get unnecessarily messy and laborious to manage.

Comment: @ DonBoitnott i also agree with you about the "messy and laborious to manage" not all the time it is the place to use lables, when i think the user should get a messege box i write a custom and designed  form instead of   `System.Windows.Forms.MessegeBox()`  UX perspective point of view..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Error Provider.  In fact, for in-place validation such as you are doing, I tend to prefer them.  I try to limit pop-up boxes, as they can be annoying to the user.  Error providers, coupled with disabling a Save button, for instance, can provide a block to continuing as well as information as to why, all without annoying pop-ups.

As for checking against items already in the list box, yes, I would loop over them checking one at a time.  If there are a lot of them, or if performance is highly critical, then you could implement a custom comparer for the items you add to the list box.  They could also be of a custom class to facilitate the mechanics of it all.

Comment: Thanks DonBoitnott ! I tried a for loop --see above ,but not working Can you see anything amiss ?

Comment: The `ToString()` is probably not returning what you think it is.  Inspect it during debug to see what I mean.